# FormItems are not aligning as ItemRenderers within a DataGroup

Tags: forms, apache-flex, layout, itemrenderer, flex-spark

I am trying to use a FormItem as an ItemRenderer within a DataGroup - the purpose being to dynamically create a Form based upon an XMLlist as a data provider.  The first part is a success in that the form items are successfully rendered, however my problem is that despite used the FormLayout in the DataGroup, my FormItem Labels are not aligning up with eachother.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
>
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XMLList id="_formModel" >
            <control description="Weeks 1 Form Item"  id="087B4626-B95E-731F-ACC7-80ED7373E083" label="One" />
            <control description="Weeks 2 Form Item"  id="AC546361-D9C5-E9F3-5F90-80EFA52EF54D" label="Second"  />
            <control description="Weeks 3 Form Item"  id="9EE2AAA4-B9C3-68C0-D9B5-80F0374F940E" label="Three" />
            <control description="Weeks 4 Form Item"  id="3CCEABD6-12F9-E511-0C77-80F0A86902D5" label="The Fourth"  />      
    </fx:XMLList> 
    <s:XMLListCollection id="_controls" source="{_formModel}"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:DataGroup width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{_controls}"  >
        <s:layout>
            <s:FormLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:ItemRenderer>
                    <s:FormItem label="{data.@label}" width="100%"  >
                        <s:TextInput  width="100%"  text="{data.@description}"/>
                    </s:FormItem>
                </s:ItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>  
    </s:DataGroup>
</s:Scroller>
</s:Application>
```

Can anyone tell me how to align the form item labels whilst still using them within a Data Group as the purpose of the exercise is to create a form Dynamically based upon data fed into a DataGroup.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question: I had some fun solving it and it turned out to be easier then I anticipated.

### The problem

The issue is that `FormItem`s must be direct children of the container that has the `FormLayout`, however in this case the `FormItem` is a child of `ItemRenderer` which in turn is a child of the `DataGroup`.

### The solution

To fix the issue, you can create a subclass of `FormItem` that also implements the `IItemRenderer` interface. That way the `DataGroup` will know what to do with the items, and the `FormItem`s will be direct children of the `FormLayout`.

### The code

First create the custom item renderer:

```
public class FormItemRenderer extends FormItem implements IItemRenderer {

    private var _data:Object;
    [Bindable("dataChange")]
    public function get data():Object { return _data; }
    public function set data(value:Object):void {
        _data = value;
        label = value ? value.@label : null;

        if (hasEventListener(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE))
            dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
    }

    private var _itemIndex:int;
    public function get itemIndex():int { return _itemIndex; }
    public function set itemIndex(value:int):void {
        if (value == _itemIndex) return;

        _itemIndex = value;
        invalidateDisplayList();
    }

    private var _selected:Boolean = false;
    public function get selected():Boolean { return _selected; }
    public function set selected(value:Boolean):void {
        if (value != _selected) {
            _selected = value;
            invalidateDisplayList();
        }
    }

    public function get dragging():Boolean { return false; }
    public function set dragging(value:Boolean):void { }

    public function get showsCaret():Boolean { return false; }
    public function set showsCaret(value:Boolean):void { }

}
```

I only implemented the bare minimum to get this to work; you can add what you need later.
Also note the second line of the `data` setter where we pass on the `label` attribute of the XML node to the `FormItem`'s `label` property. That's not a very generic way to do it, but I guess you can figure out a solution for that later, if need be.

Now use the custom renderer:

```
<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{_controls}">
    <s:layout>
        <s:FormLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <r:FormItemRenderer>
                <s:TextInput width="100%" text="{data.@description}"/>
            </r:FormItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:DataGroup>
```

### Notes

You can use this solution with a `DataGroup` out of the box, but if you want to use it with a `List` (or any other component extending `ListBase`) there's one additional thing to consider:
`FormLayout` doesn't support layout virtualization, which is turned on by default for Lists (wouldn't make sense for normal use cases anyway). So you'll have to explicitly set `useVirtualLayout` to `false` to avoid NullPointerExceptions.

```
<s:List dataProvider="{_controls}" useVirtualLayout="false">
    ...
</s:List/>
```

Comment: +1 good answer, but why won't it work w/the List? (just curious). Does the List mess up the form item layout?

Comment: @SunilD. Indeed it does. Didn't have time to dig deeper, but it throws a NPE when looping over the elements of the container at a certain point. Perhaps something to do with virtual layout.

Comment: Awesome!  RIAStar - you are not called star for nothing!  It would be great if you could get it to work with useVirtualLayout out of interest but not necessary for me.

Thanks very much - How do I 'vote' you up?

Comment: @Beaker Just hit the 'up' arrow (upvote) and/or the green checkmark (accept answer as the correct one) next to the answer.